# yii2 errorhandler: Redirect to frontend/site/error

Tags: redirect, yii2, rbac

When implementing the access control on the backend, I would like to redirect disallowed users to the frontend error page (instead of the backend error page).

The backend controller:

```
'access' => [
    'class' => AccessControl::className(),
    'rules' => [
        [
            'allow' => true,
            'roles' => ['admin'],
        ],
```

backend/config/main.php

```
'components'=>[
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
```

How do I redirect non-admin users to frontend/site/error? Everything I try results in an error.

Many thanks

Comment: a user who isn't allowed access to backend would automatically land on the login page when trying to access, I mean what you are trying to do is confusing, why are you doing this?

Comment: Thanks Muhammad. Guests are already directed to the login page. I am referring to logged in users. Only admin is allowed on the backend. Logged in users have their own page on the front end. I am trying to redirect them back to the front end if they attempt to go to the backend. Many thanks

Comment: as far as i know if you have separated sessions for front and backend it doesn't matter if the frontend user is even logged in, he would still be redirected to the login page of backend if he tries to access any page of backend

Comment: do select the answer if it helped you so other having the same problem also get the benefit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand correctly you want the frontend user **if logged in** and tries to access the backend's modules or controllers he/she should not be allowed to do so, This was a Session Sharing bug reported earlier, and this was added into [`Yii 2.0.9 milestones`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/issues/110) and is already integrated since 2016.

If you are working on an existing Yii2 project with an older version and haven't migrated or upgraded to the latest version, I would suggest you do the following settings

## `/backend/config/main.php:`

```
return [
    'id' => 'app-backend',
    // ...
    'components' => [
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\Admin',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
            'identityCookie' => [
                'name' => '_backendUser', // unique for backend
            ]
        ],
        'session' => [
            'name' => 'PHPBACKSESSID',
            'savePath' => sys_get_temp_dir(),
        ],
// ..
];
```

## `/frontend/config/main.php:`

```
return [
    'id' => 'app-frontend',
    'components' => [
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
            'identityCookie' => [
                'name' => '_frontendUser',
            ]
        ],
        'session' => [
            'name' => 'PHPFRONTSESSID',
            'savePath' => sys_get_temp_dir(),
        ],
    ///...
    ]
];
```

Comment: Thank you!! Working

Comment: glad i could help